# actuator/metrics in spring boot 2.3.x not working for kafka metrics even after adding MicrometerConsumerListener

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

I followed this https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#micrometer-native and added the micrometer consumer listener something like

```java
consumerFactory.addListener(new MicrometerConsumerListener<>(new SimpleMeterRegistry()));
```

I tried with Composite and Logging Meter registry but none of them show the metrics. In the spring documentation it shows meterRegistry() where will I get that method from?

I am setting up my own consumer factory something like

```
@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> getConsumerFactory()
    {
        DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
            addConsumerFactoryProperties(consumerProperties));
        consumerFactory.addListener(
            new MicrometerConsumerListener<String, String>(new SimpleMeterRegistry()));
        return consumerFactory;
    }

Any help appreciated

Thanks
P
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding management.metrics.web.server.request.autotime.enabled=true

Comment: But default value for this setting is true. So did it really solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the micrometer for this and use the PrometheusMeterRegistry class made available by the micrometer dependency.

**Dependency:**

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Example:

```html
@Autowired
private final PrometheusMeterRegistry meterRegistry;

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory()
{
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
        addConsumerFactoryProperties(consumerProperties));
    consumerFactory.addListener(new MicrometerConsumerListener<String, String>(meterRegistry));
    
    return consumerFactory;
}
```